# selecting and formatting by type 1 or 2 after join operation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql:

```
SELECT 
 m.member_id,
 m.login, 
 p.type 
FROM 
 permissions p
INNER JOIN members m ON p.member_id = m.member_id
WHERE 
 K_id = '$kid' 
ORDER BY p.type DESC
```

what I want to do is if p.type = 2 wrap in div id=2, and if p.type = 1 wrap in div id=1. How can this be done after a join operation?

Comment: when I echo the results of the query ...if the type is 1 then <div id = 1>

Comment: this has nothing to do with SQL, this is part of PHP (or whatever you use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're after the [CASE](http://mysql-tips.blogspot.com/2005/04/mysql-select-case-example.html) statement

```
SELECT 
 m.member_id,
 m.login, 
 p.type,
 CASE p.type 
   WHEN 1 THEN '<div id=1>' 
   WHEN 2 THEN '<div id=2>'
 END as MyDiv
FROM 
 permissions p
INNER JOIN members m ON p.member_id = m.member_id
WHERE 
 K_id = '$kid' 
ORDER BY p.type DESC
```

Comment: would an if statement inside the while loop be faster/slower?

Comment: Same speed, but I'm not sure where the while loop is

Comment: Or `CONCAT('<div id=', CAST(p.type AS CHAR), '>')` instead of `CASE`.